# ruby on rails replace single-quotes with double-quote in a string

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, double-quotes, single-quotes

I am trying to replace a single-quote with double quotes inside a string, as following:

```
current_res = 25
lowest_res = 15
str = "The result of the child is '#{current_res}' and the lowest grade is '#{lowest_res }'."
```

I need the output to look like:

```
str = The result of the child is "25" and the lowest grade is "15".
```

I tried different method using gsub but nothing work so far. Any ideas?

Comment: I just ran `puts str.gsub(/'/, '"')` Do you want to share the gsub invocation you used?

And can you clarify the output you wanted? Is that supposed to be ruby or literal string output? (If the former, that's not valid ruby code; if the latter, what command do you intend to run to give you the `str = ` at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the only case you're covering where you need to show some output in double quoted string then. How about something simple like following

```
str = "The result of the child is \"#{current_res}\" and the lowest grade is \"#{lowest_res }\" ."
```

You can escape quotes in double quoted strings.

Comment: Or `str = %Q(The result of the child is "#{current_res}" and the lowest grade is "#{lowest_res }" .)` if you want to avoid all the backslashes.